# SwiftUI state over multiple views

Tags: list, foreach, model, binding, swiftui

In SwiftUI handling the state of an app first seemed to be quite simple. There are essentially two property wrappers: `@EnvironmentObject` and `@ObservedObject` (and `@State`). But it turned out that it isn't that simple at all.

I posted several questions here. Most of them have been answered very well:
[SwiftUI onDelete List with Toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62948754/swiftui-ondelete-list-with-toggle), [SwiftUI ForEach with .indices() does not update after onDelete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62909572/swiftui-foreach-with-indices-does-not-update-after-ondelete), [SwiftUI: Index out of range when deleting cells with toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62851218/swiftui-index-out-of-range-when-deleting-cells-with-toggle)

But every time I go a step further, some principal problems stay. These are

1. Hand over a bindable variable via `NavigationLink` in a `List` or a `ForEach` to a SubView and reflecting changes back to the MainView. (I tried several solutions like working with `.indices` on the array and make a bindable on the fly ([SwiftUI onDelete List with Toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62948754/swiftui-ondelete-list-with-toggle))).
   To reflect changes back I also tried to work with `.onReceive()` which also didn't work.
2. I always run into index-problems when I try to work with this formula: `someArray.firstIndex(where {condition})!`. You can find this in the Apple tutorials for SwiftUI. I also run into problems, when I use indexes in a `ForEach`-closure and then try to swipe-delete with `.onDelete()`. The error message is:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
```

3. How can I bind variables to an `@EnvironmentObject`-model that are two or more layers behind the mainView? Working with the formula in 2. produces very long variable-names. This doesn't seem to be right.

Here is one example, which nearly works. The only thing that does not work is updating the `MainView` when I change values in the `SubViews`. But it doesn't feel right for me to use several `ObservedObjects` in my app.

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item]
    
    init(name: String, items: [Item]) {
        self.items = items
    }   
}

class Item: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    var id = UUID()
    var itemName: String
    @Published var subItems: [SubItem]
    
    init(itemName: String, payments: [SubItem]) {
        self.itemName = itemName
        self.subItems = payments
    }
}

class SubItem: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    var id = UUID()
    var isOn: Bool
    
    init(isOn: Bool) {
        self.isOn = isOn
    }
}


struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(model.items) {item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: SubView1(item: item)) {
                        HStack{
                            Text(item.itemName)
                            Text(item.subItems[0].isOn ? "True":"False") // I know: bad, but only for quick debugging reasons
                            Text(item.subItems[1].isOn ? "True":"False")
                        }
                    }.onReceive(item.objectWillChange, perform: {self.model.objectWillChange.send()})
                }.onDelete(perform: delete)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        self.model.items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
    
}

struct SubView1: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(item.subItems) {subItem in
                NavigationLink(destination: SubView2(subItem: subItem)) {
                    ToggleView(subItem: subItem)
                }
                
            }.onDelete(perform: delete)
        }
    }
    
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
           self.item.subItems.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
       }
}

struct SubView2: View {
    @ObservedObject var subItem: SubItem
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $subItem.isOn) {
            Text("Toggle-Text")
        }
    }
}


struct ToggleView: View {
    @ObservedObject var subItem: SubItem
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $subItem.isOn) {
            Text("Toggle-Text")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that you should be using one `@State` struct/`@ObservableObject` class in your `MainView`, and then pass `@Binding`s to the subviews

Comment: Firstly, your delete method in your view should be in your ViewModel ( ```@ObservableObjects``` ) or you can use ```@Binding``` in your subviews and I suppose you have a model variable somewhere so that you pass it to your MainView.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to access the binding of an item and use it in the `ToggleView`:

```
struct SubView1: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<item.subItems.count, id: \.self) { index in
                NavigationLink(destination: SubView2(subItem: self.$item.subItems[index])) { // <- pass the binding
                    ToggleView(subItem: self.$item.subItems[index]) // <- pass the binding
                }
            }.onDelete(perform: delete)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

```
struct SubView2: View {
    @Binding var subItem: SubItem // <- receive the binding
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $subItem.isOn) {
            Text("Toggle-Text")
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ToggleView: View {
    @Binding var subItem: SubItem // <- receive the binding
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $subItem.isOn) {
            Text("Toggle-Text")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello pawello2222. I tried your solution, but it didn't work. 1. When I change values on ```SubView2```, the ```MainView```does not change. 2. When I delete a row on ```SubView1```, I get the error message: ```Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range```in the ```AppDelegate```.

Comment: @Nico The solution I proposed for `ToggleView` can be applied for `SubView2` as well. I updated my answer to reflect this. *Index out of range* occurs because you remove an item but then in the main view you still try to access it: `Text(item.subItems[1].isOn ? "True" : "False")` - for this line to work you need *at least* two subitems.